# undefined index in php while uploading an image file

Tags: php

```
<?php
ob_start();
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$mysl_database = "login";

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$db_select=mysql_select_db($mysl_database, $conn);
if($conn==false ||$db_select==false)
{
    die("connection error");
}

    if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]))
{
    session_start();
}

$location="profilepics/";
$name=$_FILES['myimage']['name'];
$temp_name=$_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];
if((isset($name)))
{
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$location.$name);
    }
?>
```

I am getting this error while the page gets reload or directed towards it

> Notice: Undefined index: myimage in C:\xampp\htdocs\profilepic.php on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined index: myimage in C:\xampp\htdocs\profilepic.php on line 22

but as soon as file is uploaded errors disappear please help.below is my html code

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profilepic.php">
  <div id="box_title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <strong>I look like this: </strong></div>
  <div class="pull-right"><img src="<?php $target_file ?>" height="150px" width="200px"/></div><br />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">select a picture</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="myimage" />
    <p class="help-block">upload your photo</p>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">upload</button>
  <br />
  </form>
```

Comment: What is on line 22 of `profilepic.php`? Have you tried `var_dump($_FILES);` to make sure the data is in there how you're expecting it?

Comment: these are lines of code on line 21 & 22 $name=$_FILES['myimage']['name'];
$temp_name=$_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` database extensions, they were deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and were removed altogether in PHP 7.0.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first load the page, `$_FILES['myimage']['name']` and `$_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];` will be *undefined* because you haven't uploaded anything yet.

**The solution** is:

- First add a `name` attribute your submit button, like this:

  ```
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">upload</button>
  ```
- And wrap your form processing code inside an `if` block, like this:

  ```
  // your code

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $location="profilepics/";
      $name=$_FILES['myimage']['name'];
      $temp_name=$_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];
      if(isset($name)){
          move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$location.$name);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: but after using the above code and adding name="submit" in <button> in the code image is not getting uploaded in the "profilepics" folder

Comment: @hatim Is it the upload problem or you can't see the uploaded image here, `...<img src="<?php $target_file ?>"...`? If later one is the issue then change that line in the following way, `<div class="pull-right"><img src="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $location . $name; } ?>" height="150px" width="200px"/></div><br />`

Comment: I dont know but I cant see the image in the folder

Comment: @hatim Make sure that your *php* page and *profilepics* folder are in the same directory. Also, wrap your `move_uploaded_file()` function inside `if-else` block, like this: `if(move_uploaded_file(...)){ echo "success"; }else{ echo "failure"; }`

Comment: on removing  name="submit" from <button> image is uploading in the folder but showing index not defined error

Comment: @hatim Not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Paste your complete code on [`pastebin.com`](http://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: can I get ur email actually the pastebin.com is not responding

Comment: @hatim Before diving deep into the code, preliminary things say, 1) you didn't include `name="submit"` attribute as I suggested in my answer. 2) Are you getting any `success` or `error` message after submitting the form?

Comment: I made the changes in the code before uploading the code....and the code is showing nothing neither success or fail

Comment: @hatim I just added `name="submit"` attribute in the submit `button`, changed the upload directory(as per my system) here, `$location="profilepics/";` and it's working perfectly fine. Just check whether your `$location . $name` path is correct or not.

Comment: Are the images moving to the "profilepics/" folder ??? can you please mail me the final code in which you have made changes

Comment: thank you It finally worked..with no errors...thanks brother

Comment: @hatim You're welcome! Please mark the answer as *accepted* if resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Dude please check file var or ur form data:

```
if(isset($_FILES)){
ob_start();
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$mysl_database = "login";

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$db_select=mysql_select_db($mysl_database, $conn);
if($conn==false ||$db_select==false)
{
    die("connection error");
}

    if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]))
{
    session_start();
}

$location="profilepics/";
$name=$_FILES['myimage']['name'];
$temp_name=$_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];
if((isset($name)))
{
        move_

uploaded_file($temp_name,$location.$name);
}
}
```

Comment: i add `if(isset($_FILES))`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Seems as though he just wrapped everything in an `isset($_FILES)` if statement

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in the past, what I did to solve it was to check my form tag, in my form tag I have this, `<form action="customer_register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-date">` , the problem was I mistakenly typed "multipart/form-date" instead of "multipart/form-data"

Secondly I checked below:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $ip = getIp(); 

    $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
    $c_email = $_POST['c_email'];
    $c_pass = $_POST['c_pass'];
    $c_image = $_FILES['c_image']['name'];
    $c_image_tmp = $FILES['c_image']['tmp_name'];
    $c_country = $_POST['c_country'];
    $c_city = $_POST['c_city'];
    $c_contact = $_POST['c_contact'];
    $c_address = $_POST['c_address'];
```

After checking the above I realized I have mistakenly typed `$FILES` instead of `$_FILES`

The above scenario implies that if you get such a prompt `Notice: Undefined index: myimage in C:\xampp\htdocs`, it is best to check carefully through the form tag and isset() funtion in PHP to identify any possible mistake.